# Jquery accordion - keyboard accessiblity

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I noticed in jquery accordion ui, it doesn't use keyboard tabs. Instead it's UP and DOWN key once you land on the first element. Does this behavior make sense? i always thought you used tab key to change links if you're using  a keyboard.

Comment: a reason may be that `tab` can only go down. It would be inconsistent to use `tab` for `going down` and `up arrow` or something else for `going up`. But then again it can be any key. ( I personally prefer tab only to switch focus of inputs)

Comment: wouldn't it be better to have tab + up and down work with ui accordion? How do i implement something like this?

Comment: Any idea how to add additinoal keyboard tab support to accordion?